# Getting closest class using jQuery

Tags: jquery, closest

I'm trying to grab the the text in the closest element with a class name of 'the_text' but I'm missing something obvious.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.click-class', function(e) {
  var t = $(this);

  alert(t.closest('.the_text').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class="the_text">Grab This Text</span>
  <p>
    &nbsp;
  </p>
  <span><a class="click-class">Click</a></span>
</div>
```

The result when clicking 'Click' is empty but I'm expecting it to be 'Grab This Text'

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/7c9w3f62/

Comment: Did you read up on what [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) does?  *For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through **its ancestors** in the DOM tree* - ie "closest" = "closest parent" - not "nearest in the html"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) only searches itself and traverses up through its ancestors

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

You will need to get the closest `div` and then use `find`

```js
$(document).on('click', '.click-class', function(e) {
  var t = $(this);

  alert(t.closest('div').find(".the_text").text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class="the_text">Grab This Text</span>
  <p>
    &nbsp;
  </p>
  <span><a class="click-class">Click</a></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Not unsurprisingly, this question has been covered many times in the past...

Comment: @jamiec thank you. Your response helped me.